# How to open outlook window with attachment from Dynamics NAV Page actions method?

Tags: outlook, html-email, nav, microsoft-dynamics

I have to send an email with attachment when clicking on 'Email' action button of the Dynamics NAV PAge action.
When the user clicks on the Email button, the standard outlook message window opens and attaches the file to it.  The filename is the subject.

Comment: _"When the user clicks on the Email button, the standard outlook message window opens and attaches the file to it."_ To be clear: is this what you *want* to happen, not what *currently* happens?

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by using Codeunit 397. There are two functions for that:

```
CreateMessage(ToAddresses,CcAddresses,BccAddresses,Subject,Body,ShowNewMailDialogOnSend,RunModal);
AttachFile(AttachFilename);
```

Depending on your Dynamics NAV Version, the Parameter could be slightly changed.

Comment: And how would they actually use these functions to do what they want? Just quoting the API symbols without any idea of how they should be used is not hugely helpful.

Comment: To open an Outlook Window with an attachment you should create a new Page Action and create a local Variable of Type Codeunit 397 inside. In that Action you call these two methods and replace the parameters with the actual e-mail address, subject, file name of the attachment and so on.